# Nginx - Laravel and Reactjs in single config

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, nginx

I need to setup staging for my react/laravel project.The laravel serves as api and the react is an stand alone reactjs create-react-app.

What I want to achieve is to have a domain like this

```
   project.staging-site.com // as the main site
   project.staging-site.com/backend // as the laravel site
```

Inside laravel, I have also a dashboard that is also built with reactjs(not by create-react-app) but by the default configuration by running the laravel built in frontend scaffolding.

So in my localhost, backend looks likes this

```
   localhost:8000 // where the dashboard lives
   localhost:8000/api/V1 //where the api routes lives(consumed by the reactjs frontend)
   localhost:8000/admin/V1 // where the admin routes lives(consumed by the reactjs dashboard)
```

And my frontend looks like this

```
   localhost:3000
```

I tried this nginx config, the frontend works, but the backend part returns 404

```
    project.staging-site.com/backend
    project.staging-site.com/backend/admin
    file not found.
```

Here is my nginx

```
    server {
           listen 80;
           server_name project.staging-site.com;
           root /portal/front/build;

           add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
           add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
           add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

           charset utf-8;

           location /backend/ {
              root /portal/backend/current/public;
              try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
           }

           location / {
              root /portal/front/build;
              try_files $uri /index.html;
           }
           location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
           location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

           error_page 404 /index.php;

           location ~ \.php$ {
               fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
               fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
               include fastcgi_params;
           }

           location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
               deny all;
           }
      }
```

And here's my route for the backend dashboard

```
      Route::get('/', function () {
          return view('index');
      });
      
      ///////React
      Route::group(["prefix" => "admin"], function () {
           /*
           |---------------------------------------------------------------------------
           | React Routes
           |---------------------------------------------------------------------------
           */

           Route::view('/{path?}', 'index');
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar configuration in one of my projects - with front-end react app, and back-end in Laravel(no React in back-end though).

Here is what I did to deploy them on nginx.

I created separate server configs for front-end and back-end, with different listen ports for each.
Verify the route configs and ensure that the front-end hits the right back-end urls.

Also, add log configs in nginx config as given below so that you have some more information when you get some errors.

```
 error_log /var/log/nginx/laravel-app-error.log;
 access_log /var/log/nginx/laravel-app-access.log;
```

Hope this gives you some idea to find the root cause for the 404 error.